# How to deal with sewage on a map with no water anywhere

Tags: cities-skylines

Some downloadable maps for Cities Skylines start you in a land-locked square with no water, but a drain pipe is the only option I can find for getting rid of sewage. Is there a way to get rid of sewage without access to a body of water?

I've seen some posts on reddit about using a canal, but canals aren't available for quite some time after starting a new city.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are happy to use other than vanilla drainage buildings you can use following.

1. [Quad's Water Purifer](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=547840664) (*does not require any road connection*) or
2. [Modular sewage treatment facility](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=565043158)

However if you are not happy with those two options you can do the terra-forming and create a lake using following mod in which you can put / place sewage building.

- [Extra Landscaping Tools](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=502750307)

Hope this helps.